# Wrong if-else cases in Python

Tags: python

Can someone please look at this and tell me what's wrong? 
I tried running it but when you say `no` for raining and `no` for snowing , it still prints out the if true statement `You can't ride your bike`

```
raining = input("Is it raining right now?\nYes or No?\n")
if raining.lower() == "yes" :
    raining = True
else:
    raining = False
snowing = input("Is it snowing out?\nYes or No\n")
if snowing.lower() == "yes" :
    snowing = True
else:
    snowing = False
if raining or snowing == True :
    print("You can't ride your bike")
if raining and snowing == False :
    print("You can ride your bike")

cost = input("How much is your new PC?")
cash = input("How much money do you have?")
total = float(cash) + float(cost)
if total < 0 :
    print("You can't buy it")
if total >= 0 :
    print ("You can buy it")
```

Comment: Do you know `if raining or snowing == True` is interpreted as `if (raining) or (snowing == True)` not `if raining == True or snowing == True`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if raining and snowing == False` is interpreted as:

```
if raining == True and snowing == False
```

You should update your second `if` statement as follows:

```
if raining == False and snowing == False:
    ...
```

Since `if raining` and `if raining == True` are identical for checking boolean values, you can simplify your logic like this:

```
if raining or snowing:
    print("You can't ride your bike")
else:
    # implies "not (raining or snowing)" or "(not raining) and (not snowing)"
    print("You can ride your bike")
```

Comment: You can simplify that to `if raining and snowing` and `if not (raining or snowing)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `and` condition to `else`and use brackets in the `or` condition.

```
raining = input("Is it raining right now?\nYes or No?\n")

if raining.lower() == "yes" :
    raining = True
else:
    raining = False
snowing = input("Is it snowing out?\nYes or No\n")

if snowing.lower() == "yes" :
    snowing = True
else:
    snowing = False
if (raining or snowing) == True :
    print("You can't ride your bike")
else:
    print("You can ride your bike")

cost = input("How much is your new PC?")
cash = input("How much money do you have?")
total = float(cash) + float(cost)
if total < 0 :
    print("You can't buy it")
if total >= 0 :
    print ("You can buy it")
```